# elasticsearch : EC2 discovery : master nodes work data nodes fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

My objective is to run a 6 node cluster on three instances in EC2. 
I am placing one master-only and one data-only node on each instance (using the elastic ansible playbook).

The master nodes from each of the three instances all find each other without issue using EC2 discovery and form a cluster of three and elect a master. 
The data nodes from the same instances fail on startup with the error below.

**What have I tried**
- switching data nodes to explicit zen.unicast discovery via hostnames works
- I can telnet on port 9301 from instance A->B without issue

**REFERENCE:**
java version - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
es version - 2.1.0

data node elasticseach.yml

```
bootstrap.mlockall: false
cloud.aws.region: us-east
cluster.name: my-cluster
discovery.ec2.groups: stage-elasticsearch
discovery.ec2.host_type: private_dns
discovery.ec2.ping_timeout: 30s
discovery.type: ec2
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
gateway.expected_nodes: 4
http.port: 9201
network.host: _ec2:privateDns_
node.data: true
node.master: false
transport.tcp.port: 9301
node.name: ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1
```

master node elasticsearch.yml

```
bootstrap.mlockall: false
cloud.aws.region: us-east
cluster.name: my-cluster
discovery.ec2.groups: stage-elasticsearch
discovery.ec2.host_type: private_dns
discovery.ec2.ping_timeout: 30s
discovery.type: ec2
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
gateway.expected_nodes: 4
http.port: 9200
network.host: _ec2:privateDns_
node.data: false 
node.master: true 
transport.tcp.port: 9300
node.name: ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-master
```

Errors from datanode startup:

```
[2016-03-02 15:45:06,246][INFO ][node                     ] [ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1] initializing ...
[2016-03-02 15:45:06,679][INFO ][plugins                  ] [ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1] loaded [cloud-aws], sites [head]
[2016-03-02 15:45:06,710][INFO ][env                      ] [ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/xvda1)]], net usable_space [11.5gb], net total_space [14.6gb], spins? [no], types [ext4]
[2016-03-02 15:45:09,597][INFO ][node                     ] [ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1] initialized
[2016-03-02 15:45:09,597][INFO ][node                     ] [ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1] starting ...
[2016-03-02 15:45:09,678][INFO ][transport                ] [ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1] publish_address {ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1/xxx-xxx-xx-xxx:9301}, bound_addresses {xxx-xxx-xx-xxx:9301}
[2016-03-02 15:45:09,687][INFO ][discovery                ] [ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1] my-cluster/PNI6WAmzSYGgZcX2HsqenA
[2016-03-02 15:45:09,701][WARN ][com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport]
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanServerPermission" "findMBeanServer")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.checkPermission(MBeanServerFactory.java:413)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:361)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.getMBeanServer(MBeans.java:111)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.registerMBean(MBeans.java:50)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.registerMetricAdminMBean(SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.registerMetricAdminMBean(AwsSdkMetrics.java:355)
    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.<clinit>(AwsSdkMetrics.java:316)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.requestMetricCollector(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:563)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.isRMCEnabledAtClientOrSdkLevel(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:504)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.isRequestMetricsEnabled(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:496)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.createExecutionContext(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:457)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeInstances(AmazonEC2Client.java:5924)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.ec2.AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.fetchDynamicNodes(AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.java:118)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.ec2.AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider$DiscoNodesCache.refresh(AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.java:230)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.ec2.AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider$DiscoNodesCache.refresh(AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.java:215)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.SingleObjectCache.getOrRefresh(SingleObjectCache.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.ec2.AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.buildDynamicNodes(AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing.sendPings(UnicastZenPing.java:335)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing.ping(UnicastZenPing.java:240)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.ZenPingService.ping(ZenPingService.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.ZenPingService.pingAndWait(ZenPingService.java:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.findMaster(ZenDiscovery.java:879)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innerJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:335)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$5000(ZenDiscovery.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$JoinThreadControl$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:1236)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-03-02 15:45:09,703][WARN ][com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics]
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanServerPermission" "findMBeanServer")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.checkPermission(MBeanServerFactory.java:413)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:361)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.getMBeanServer(MBeans.java:111)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.isRegistered(MBeans.java:98)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.isMBeanRegistered(SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.registerMetricAdminMBean(AwsSdkMetrics.java:361)
    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.<clinit>(AwsSdkMetrics.java:316)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.requestMetricCollector(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:563)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.isRMCEnabledAtClientOrSdkLevel(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:504)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.isRequestMetricsEnabled(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:496)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.createExecutionContext(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:457)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeInstances(AmazonEC2Client.java:5924)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.ec2.AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.fetchDynamicNodes(AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.java:118)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.ec2.AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider$DiscoNodesCache.refresh(AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.java:230)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.ec2.AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider$DiscoNodesCache.refresh(AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.java:215)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.SingleObjectCache.getOrRefresh(SingleObjectCache.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.ec2.AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.buildDynamicNodes(AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing.sendPings(UnicastZenPing.java:335)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing.ping(UnicastZenPing.java:240)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.ZenPingService.ping(ZenPingService.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.ZenPingService.pingAndWait(ZenPingService.java:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.findMaster(ZenDiscovery.java:879)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innerJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:335)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$5000(ZenDiscovery.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$JoinThreadControl$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:1236)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-03-02 15:45:39,688][WARN ][discovery                ] [ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
[2016-03-02 15:45:39,698][INFO ][http                     ] [ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1] publish_address {ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1/xxx-xxx-xx-xxx:9201}, bound_addresses {xxx-xxx-xx-xxx:9201}
[2016-03-02 15:45:39,699][INFO ][node                     ] [ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.vpc.fakedomain.com-data1] started
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the explicit setting of transport.tcp.port: 9300 and using the default of letting it pick any ports in the range 9300-9399.

The warnings from the AwsSdkMetrics remain but are NOT an issue as Val stated.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually an error.

See [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14013) where this has been reported. It just seems the plugin is logging too much.

If you modify your `logging.yml` config file as suggested in that issue with this, then you'll be fine:

```
# aws will try to do some sketchy JMX stuff, but its not needed.
com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport: ERROR
com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics: ERROR
```

Comment: fair enough, but it does appear to be impacting ec2 discovery, since these data nodes cant seem to join the cluster unless I turn off ec2 discovery and explictly set zen.unicast.ping hosts list.